# How can I make a search bar in a my ListView

Tags: flutter, searchbar

How can I make a search bar in this list view that have list of data I tried searching on YouTube but I always get errors and none of them worked

```
// ignore_for_file: use_key_in_widget_constructors, avoid_print, avoid_unnecessary_containers, curly_braces_in_flow_control_structures, prefer_const_constructors, non_constant_identifier_names, unnecessary_new, avoid_function_literals_in_foreach_calls, unused_import
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:myapp2/Service_Request/SR.dart';
import 'package:myapp2/main.dart';
import 'package:myapp2/Service_Request/second.dart';
import '../Classes/demandes.dart';
import 'SR_details.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: DataFromAPI(),
    );
  }
}

class DataFromAPI extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DataFromAPIState createState() => _DataFromAPIState();
}

List<Attributes> MyAllData = [];

class _DataFromAPIState extends State<DataFromAPI> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<List<Sr>> loadData() async {
    try {
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(
          'http://192.168.1.30:9080/maxrest/rest/mbo/sr/?_lid=azizl&_lpwd=max12345m&_format=json'));
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        final jsonBody = json.decode(response.body);
        Demandes data = Demandes.fromJson(jsonBody);
        final srAttributes = data.srMboSet.sr;
        return srAttributes;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
    throw Exception("");
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: new Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Liste des Demandes'),
          leading: IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
              onPressed: () => Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SR()))),
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Sr>?>(
          future: loadData(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            } else {
              return new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data?.length,
                  itemBuilder: ((_, index) {
                    return new ListTile(
                        title: new Card(
                          margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                              vertical: 2.0, horizontal: 8.0),
                          elevation: 10,
                          child: new ListTile(
                            title: new Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0)),
                                new Text(
                                    'Ticket ID  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.ticketid.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'status  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.status.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'description  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.description?.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'Reported by  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.reportedby.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'Location  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.location?.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'Asset num  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.assetnum?.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'Asset site id  : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.assetsiteid?.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'Reoprt date : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.statusdate.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'LONG DESCRIPTION : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION?.content}'),
                                new Text(
                                    'ticket u id : ${snapshot.data![index].attributes.ticketuid.content}'),
                              ],
                            ),
                            trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios_rounded),
                          ),
                        ),
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context)
                              .push(
                                new MaterialPageRoute(
                                  builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                      new SrDetailsScreen(
                                          sr: snapshot.data![index]),
                                ),
                              )
                              .then((data) {});
                        });
                  }));
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      // Remove the debug banner
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Kindacode.com',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  // This holds a list of fiction users
  // You can use data fetched from a database or a server as well
  final List<Map<String, dynamic>> _allUsers = [
    {"id": 1, "name": "Andy", "age": 29},
    {"id": 2, "name": "Aragon", "age": 40},
    {"id": 3, "name": "Bob", "age": 5},
    {"id": 4, "name": "Barbara", "age": 35},
    {"id": 5, "name": "Candy", "age": 21},
    {"id": 6, "name": "Colin", "age": 55},
    {"id": 7, "name": "Audra", "age": 30},
    {"id": 8, "name": "Banana", "age": 14},
    {"id": 9, "name": "Caversky", "age": 100},
    {"id": 10, "name": "Becky", "age": 32},
  ];

  // This list holds the data for the list view
  List<Map<String, dynamic>> _foundUsers = [];
  @override
  initState() {
    // at the beginning, all users are shown
    _foundUsers = _allUsers;
    super.initState();
  }

  // This function is called whenever the text field changes
  void _runFilter(String enteredKeyword) {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> results = [];
    if (enteredKeyword.isEmpty) {
      // if the search field is empty or only contains white-space, we'll display all users
      results = _allUsers;
    } else {
      results = _allUsers
          .where((user) =>
              user["name"].toLowerCase().contains(enteredKeyword.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
      // we use the toLowerCase() method to make it case-insensitive
    }

    // Refresh the UI
    setState(() {
      _foundUsers = results;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Anand'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            TextField(
              onChanged: (value) => _runFilter(value),
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Search', suffixIcon: Icon(Icons.search)),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: _foundUsers.isNotEmpty
                  ? ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: _foundUsers.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Card(
                        key: ValueKey(_foundUsers[index]["id"]),
                        color: Colors.amberAccent,
                        elevation: 4,
                        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                        child: ListTile(
                          leading: Text(
                            _foundUsers[index]["id"].toString(),
                            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          ),
                          title: Text(_foundUsers[index]['name']),
                          subtitle: Text(
                              '${_foundUsers[index]["age"].toString()} years old'),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )
                  : const Text(
                      'No results found',
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                    ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```